# PHP: Calling a user-defined function inside constructor?

Tags: php, function, methods, constructor

I have a class `userAuth` inside its constructor I have added code to check the user is valid or not, if there is no value in session then I check cookies (as a part of "Remember Me" feature), if there is some value inside cookies then I call a function `ConfirmUser` to check its authenticity from database. On the basis of value returned by the confirmUser function I am returning a bool (true or fales) value in constructor.

I have created my class as:

```
<?php
    class userAuth {

        function userAuth(){
            //code
        }

        function confirmUser($username, $password){
                   //code
        }
    }

    $signin_user = new userAuth();

?>
```

`confirmUser` function take two string type parameters and return return a integer value of 0, 1, 2.

I can't add code of `confirmUser` function inside the constructor as I am using this function at some more places in my application.

So, I want to know how to call a user-defined function inside constructor in PHP. Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Put some code in question. There is no difference where to call function.

Comment: Ensure include/require for function declaration of confirmUser, and you can call `confirmUser` inside constructor...what is the problem?

Comment: You said you're returning a bool in the constructor which is a bit strange. A constructor cannot return anything but an instance of its class. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

$this->nameOfFunction()

But when they are in a class, they are called Methods.

Comment: I suspect you thought that until the constructor was complete, there wasn't a '$this' to call methods on; but there is. In PHP the new object exists, and '$this' points to it, as soon as it enters the constructor.

Answer (score 9):

Be careful with using $this in a constructor, though, because in an extension hierarchy, it can cause unexpected behaviour:

```
<?php

class ParentClass {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->action();
    }

    public function action() {
        echo 'parent action' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->action();
    }

    public function action() {
        echo 'child action' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$child = new ChildClass();
```

Output:

```
child action
child action
```

Whereas:

```
class ParentClass {
    public function __construct() {
        self::action();
    }

    public function action() {
        echo 'parent action' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        self::action();
    }

    public function action() {
        echo 'child action' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$child = new ChildClass();
```

Output:

```
parent action
child action
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining this very important difference between `this` and `self::`

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between calling a function inside a constructor and calling from somewhere else. If the method is declared  in the same class you should use `$this->function()`

By the way, in php5 you are suggested to name your constructor like this:
`function __construct()`

If not then put `public` keyword before your constructor definition like this `public function userAuth()`

Answer (score 2):

you can call with $this

```
<?php
    class userAuth {

        function userAuth($username, $password){
             $this->confirmUser($username, $password);
        }

        function confirmUser($username, $password){
                   //code
        }
    }

    $signin_user = new userAuth($username, $password);

?>
```